# how to read the data from a text file to inssert to mongodb in java script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, file

I have a sample data file which contains few hundred records as shown below

```
{
"roadInfo": {
            "roadId": "1",
            "roadName": "Airport Boulevard",
            "laneCount": 5
        },
data:123
},
{
"roadInfo": {
            "roadId": "1",
            "roadName": "Airport Boulevard",
            "laneCount": 5
        },
data:123
} 
.
.
.
.
.
.
n
```

I am looking for a way to read this json payload and insert in a mongodb  collection (now i am manually inserting it)

Can some one please point out way to do it

Comment: Are you using any server side or is this all client javascript?

Comment: You might be able to use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

Comment: i am using nodejs for server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `mongoimport` for that.  While connected to the `mongod` instance that your db exists on with the `mongo` shell, run a command like `mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file file.json`.

While this is specifically made to import JSON files created from `mongoexport`, mongoimport should work as long as it doesn't violate the use of strict data types explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#considerations).

The other options is writing an import using Node.js [fs.readFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) methods and the [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) driver or a wrapper/ORM of your choice (mongoose, monk, mongoskin, etc.). [And here's a decent article on how to read the JSON file in Node](https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/how-to-use-json-files-in-node-js).